# How to fix error “ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python.” when trying to install djangorestframework-extensions using pip

Tags: python, django, linux

I am trying to install djangorestframework-extensions using the command:

```
pip install djangorestframework-extensions
```

and it shows the error:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/anamaria/workspace/licenta/AllFest2/festivals/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-r9q6vdlo/djangorestframework-extensions/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-r9q6vdlo/djangorestframework-extensions/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-r9q6vdlo/djangorestframework-extensions/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-r9q6vdlo/djangorestframework-extensions/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-r9q6vdlo/djangorestframework-extensions/setup.py", line 48
        print "You probably want to also tag the version now:"
                                                             ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("You probably want to also tag the version now:")?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

What should i do?

Comment: What version of Django and Python are you using?  What is the output when you type `pip --version`?

Comment: If you have python version 3+ then use `pip3 install djangorestframework-extensions`

Comment: @FiddleStix the python version is: `pip 20.0.2 from /home/anamaria/workspace/AllFest2/festivals/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)'`

Comment: @ans2human i've tried and i still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

this package seems to suffer incompatibilities between Python2 and python3.
you can try to fix "/tmp/pip-install-r9q6vdlo/djangorestframework-extensions/setup.py" by hand replacing all '''print something''' by '''print(something)'''
it might fail so if you have the choice it's probably better to run it with python 2 despite python two is now old.